# DATE_FORMAT compare with string and number

Tags: mysql

I believed I was a proficient mysql user, but apparently I'm not.

I thought mysql would cast things before a compare, but this query baffled me:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT('2019-07-19 12:05:12', '%H') >= '11' AND DATE_FORMAT('2019-07-19 12:05:12', '%H') <= '7' AS 'str',
  DATE_FORMAT('2019-07-19 12:05:12', '%H') >= 11 AND DATE_FORMAT('2019-07-19 12:05:12', '%H') <= 7 AS 'num';

   str     num  
------  --------
     1         0
```

So how does the compare really works? What gets casted to what?

Comment: In first expression, no casting is required, as it is string-to-string comparison. and `'12'` is greater than `'11'`, but smaller than `'7'`. In the second expression, MySQL will implicitly typecast the result of `date_format(..)` to integer `12`, and then compare. So `12 >= 11` returns true but `12 <= 7` returns false; thus you get zero for second expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, there actually doesn't appear to be any casting here at all, as `DATE_FORMAT` returns a string.  The comparison being made is:

```
SELECT
    '12' >= '11' AND '12' <= '7' AS str
```

This true, because the *text* `'12'` is lexicographically greater than `'11'`, and `'12'` is also "less" than `'7'` because the former starts with `1`.

In the second case, the RHS of the inequalities are integers, and MySQL is casting the text numbers on the LHS to integers to do the comparison:

```
SELECT
    12 >= 11 AND 12 <= 7
```

This is false, which is the expected behavior for these inequalities using actual numbers.